# How to wait until the whole page has loaded?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

There is a problem with waiting elements on the page.

Page contains a list of 20 items
I can set 100 instead 20 and page reloading with JS (child frame is reloading)

but then i got an error:
Element is no longer valid

```
moveTNVPage.switchToThisPage();
moveTNVPage.selectQuantity();
waitForPageLoad();
moveTNVPage.selectEnabledCheckBox(wait);
```

waitForPageLoad()  :

```
public void waitForPageLoad() {
        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                System.out.println("Current Window State       : " + String.valueOf(((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState")));
                return String.valueOf(((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState")).equals("complete");
            }
        });
    }
```

in @BeforeTest
i have set:

```
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

only thread.sleep() with long time can help with this problem
but on different test environment i need different thread.sleep!

How i can avoid thread.sleep????
I've tried to use

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions ... ...)
```

this also doesn't helped.

B.R.
Anton

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use:

```
public void waitForLoad(WebDriver driver) {
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> pageLoadCondition = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
        }
    };
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
    wait.until(pageLoadCondition);
}
```

As clear from the statement, this wait for the document state to be complete.
Currently the timeout is set to 60 seconds, which can be changed.

You just need to call it using `waitForLoad(driver);` wherever you need to wait for page load.

Comment: Thanks,  i'll try it.
Now i've catch ajax indicator and wait untill it becomes invisible.
it helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

This allows to execute what's inside only when page has loaded:

```
document.ready(function(){

    // Your code

});
```

And this is a way to set a delay:

```
delay = 500;    //  <-- This is in milliseconds
setTimeout(function(){

    // Your code to be executed after the delay

},delay);
```

You can use `setTimeout()` inside a `document.ready()`...